# Get specific channel depth with ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Is it possible to get the bit depth of a specific channel with an ImageMagick command?

I can see the individual channel depths with `convert :rose -verbose info:`, but I was wondering if there was a trick to only getting to print the alpha depth.

The reason I'm doing this is because I'm trying to write a script to figure out if an image either:

- Does not support transparency (like JPEG)
- Only supports ON/OFF transparency (like GIF)
- Supports >1 bit transparency (like PNG)

I can check if the image is fully opaque with `identify %[opaque] :rose`, and was thinking I could check the type of transparency by checking if the alpha bit depth is greater than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through some agonizing searching and trial and error, I may have figured it out. If I run

`convert rose: -channel A -separate -format %[fx:z] info:-`

I get the number of bits in the alpha channel. For PNGs it seems to print 8, for JPEGs and GIFs it prints 1.

Comment: `:rose is not proper IM syntax. It should be rose: ` My command should have worked. But it may be that your IM version is too old. You never mentioned what version and platform. It is always a good idea to provide that information, since syntax may vary and new features are added all the time.

Comment: @fmw42 my bad, I always switch the position of the `:`. I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.6-7 Q16, the dynamic dll option on 64-bit Windows with legacy utils installed.

Comment: The rose: image is totally opaque (and a PNM format), but 8/1 bit, so it should return 8 for the depth. On my Mac OS X Sierra with IM 6.9.9.9, I get 8 for convert rose: -format "%z" info: and also 8 for convert rose: -channel a -separate -format "%z" info:.  Similarly for IM 7.0.6.9, I get 8 for magick rose: -format "%z" info: and 8 for magick rose: -channel a -separate -format "%z" info:  So I am not sure why you are getting 1. To get 1, I think you need to check the number of colors in the alpha channel.

Comment: P.S. Imagemagick 7 uses the syntax magick in place of convert. With convert you may be getting the legacy Imagemagick 6 processing. Also I made a mistake. the rose image is PPM, not PNM.

Comment: If %[colors] does not work in IM 7, then on unix, you can do `magick rose: -channel a -separate +channel -unique-colors txt: | tail -n +2 | wc -l`. That returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick to get the bit depth of the alpha channel, try

```
convert transparent_image -alpha extract -format "%z\n" info:
```

or

```
convert transparent_image -alpha extract -format "%[depth]\n" info:
```

See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

For example:

```
convert logo: -transparent white -alpha extract -format "%z" info:
```

8

However, this may actually be binary, but listed as 8-bits.

So you might want to look at the histogram or unique-colors to see how many actual colors exist.

```
convert logo: -transparent white -alpha extract -format "%[colors]\n" info:
```

2

Comment: Afraid this didn't work. It returns 8 for JPEG, PNG and GIF, despite GIF clearly stating "1-bit" when I run the verbose command

Comment: AFAIK, GIF only supports `transparent` or `not-transparent`, there are no degrees of transparency available such as `75%`, just `0%` and `100%` so you may need to make a special check for GIFs.

Comment: `%[colors]` gives an error for me with IM v7.0.6-1 despite the documentation saying it was introduced at v7.0.3. However, `%k` works instead and correctly shows 2 (degrees of transparency) for GIFs with transparency, per your last example.